# What is the precedence of operators in C# Preprocessor Directives?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence

If I have a piece of code written in C# wrapped in an `#if` directive, what (if any) precedence is applied to any boolean operators that might be used in that directive?

In other words:

```
#if DEBUG || MYTEST && PLATFORM_WINDOWS
// ... Some code here
#endif
```

Will that be simply evaluated left to right as

```
#if (DEBUG || MYTEST) && PLATFORM_WINDOWS
```

And similarly, would

```
#if PLATFORM_WINDOWS && DEBUG || MYTEST
```

Be evaluated as

```
#if (PLATFORM_WINDOWS && DEBUG) || MYTEST
```

Or is there some precedence order for && vs ||?

Edit: To be clear, I am well aware that I can run the code myself to test it, and I have.  I'm looking for an answer that gives me something official - a reference to documentation or the like, which can give me a deeper understanding of the underlying mechanics of directives.  I'd like to know if there is a specifically intended behaviour or if this is purely something that is undefined.

Comment: IMO parenthesis should be used anyways, to avoid thinking overhead and such confusion

Comment: Why not run some tests and tell us? This is something you could easily find out for yourself.

Comment: The simple solution, which also has huge readability benefits, is to just parenthesize it yourself.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I agree that parentheses should be used anyway, I'm just asking to satisfy some curiosity.

Comment: @Blobinator: Is it really that hard to come up with an experiment that tells you the answer?

Comment: Using different precedence from normal C# would have been a pretty stupid design decision. So I'd be very surprised if it'd differ from normal C#.

Comment: @BobHorn As far as I can tell from my tests, it is evaluated left to right.  However, I'm looking for a more official answer (ideally something that points to some official documentation) to have a more complete understanding.  My own tests are fine, but it would be nice to know if my findings are intended behaviour, or simply something undefined that just happens to work this way right now.

Comment: I think this is a fine question that is presented in a clear and concise manner. The answer is not trivially found on google (that is on MSDN without diving into a specification) and - IMOHO - most of the "good" questions on SO can be answered by the poster with enough experimentation (are you seriously nitpikcing that the OP even created an example?!?). Also, having an answer for this question does increase the value/knowledge of SO.

Comment: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MPSG7E) is your friend.

Comment: You already have the code.  You only need to execute it.  Doing so would have taken you *far* less time than you've spent writing this question.

Comment: @Mehrdad It's not a matter of figuring out what happens in my program, that's simple (and as mentioned above, I always add parens to clarify the order of evaluation anyway).  I'm looking for something more official, to understand the underlying mechanics of directives better.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would be surprised too, but I'd much rather know "for certain" or at least have a reference backing me up.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I disagree; I omit parenthesis most of the time in C# expressions, except when they add clarity. Why should they be included in preprocessor directives, except for lack of clarification on the rules (which should, and can, be fixed)?

Comment: @Blobinator: I don't understand, there isn't much "mechanics" to it. C# isn't C++ where this sort of thing might be undefined, the definition is exactly equal to whatever the compiler does....

Comment: @Mehrdad I disagree - the definition is exactly equal to what the specification says. C# has an official formal specification (as opposed to a language like Ruby where the definition is effectively defined by the reference implementation).

Comment: @user2864740: Uh, the compiler does exactly what the specification says, unless you have reason to believe there might be a bug in the implementation of something trivial like this.

Comment: @Mehrdad It *should*, yes. A question such as this should be addressed in terms of such a specification (it will either be defined or or it will not be) and backed with results of the implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **2.5.2 Pre-processing expressions**
>
> Evaluation of a pre-processing expression always yields a boolean
>   value. **The rules of evaluation for a pre-processing expression are the
>   same as those for a constant expression (§7.19)**, except that the only
>   user-defined entities that can be referenced are conditional
>   compilation symbols

> *7.19* Constant expressions
>
> **The compile-time evaluation of constant expressions uses the same rules as run-time evaluation of non-constant expressions***, except that where run-time evaluation would have thrown an exception, compile-time evaluation causes a compile-time error to occur.

So the same operator precedence applies to pre-processing expressions, constant expressions and runtime evaluation.

> **7.3.1 Operator precedence and associativity**
>
> (...)
>
> 7.11 Logical AND  &
>
> 7.11 Logical XOR  ^
>
> 7.11 Logical OR   |
>
> 7.12 Conditional AND  &&
>
> 7.12 Conditional OR   ||
>
> (...)

From highest to lowest precedence.

Comment: Wow that was fast - is that an older spec the one i was looking at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf has 2.5.2 at 9.5.2 etc

Comment: It's from C# 5.0 spec. The one you linked to is 2006 :) C# spec is part of VS installation resources now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Comment: ah that explains it - thought lower numbers meant older

Answer (score 7):

See *2.5.2 Pre-processing expressions* in the *C# Language Specification Version 5.0*.

The specification doesn't talk about operator precedence, but it follows from the BNF grammar given in that section.

1. Parentheses, constants (`true`, `false`) and conditional-symbols (`PLATFORM_WINDOWS`, `DEBUG` etc.)
2. Unary `!`
3. Equality `==`, `!=`
4. And `&&`
5. Or `||`

It also says:

> When referenced in a pre-processing expression, a defined conditional compilation symbol has the boolean value true, and an undefined conditional compilation symbol has the boolean value false.
>
> Evaluation of a pre-processing expression always yields a boolean value. The rules of evaluation for a pre-processing expression are the same as those for a constant expression (§7.19), except that the only user-defined entities that can be referenced are conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of that citation, what it means in practical terms is that, while `#if FOO == FOO` is always be **true**, it's only because in this special case the condition ("FOO is (not) defined") will *always* equal the condition ("FOO is (not) defined"). To see that these "variables" don't have proper identities however, just consider that if "BAR" also happens to be "defined," then `FOO == BAR` is also true. Conversely, `FOO != BAR` prevails when the two are in opposite "defined" states, `true/false` or `false/true`.

Answer (score 2):

The precedence in preprocessor directives is the same as the [usual precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx): `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. To demonstrate this, run the following code:

```
#undef A
#define B
#define C
#if A && B || C
    Console.WriteLine(1);
#endif
#if (A && B) || C
    Console.WriteLine(2);
#endif
#if A && (B || C)
    Console.WriteLine(3);
#endif
#if B || C && A
    Console.WriteLine(4);
#endif
#if B || (C && A)
    Console.WriteLine(5);
#endif
#if (B || C) && A
    Console.WriteLine(6);
#endif
```

The output is:

```
1
2
4
5
```

Which shows that the parentheses are equivalent when they're around the `&&`, not the two items on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the && operator has higher precedence than the || Operator in C# as shown here, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So your code would then be evaluated :

```
#if DEBUG || MYTEST && PLATFORM_WINDOWS
// ... Some code here
#endif
```

would be evaluated as

```
#if (MYTEST && PLATFORM_WINDOWS) || DEBUG
// ... Some code here
#endif
```

Comment: This is true for C# expressions (and most every other language), but I have no been able to find a reference that explicitly states this holds true for C# *preprocess* conditionals. Showing an actual tested result would add evidence to the claim, finding an official reference/specification, even more so.

Comment: @user2864740 That's exactly what the OP was asked to do in the comments against the question!